# Why can't i list directory in filezilla?

Tags: ftp

Connection mode: Active

While connection to the ftp it displays

```
Command:    PORT 110,44,125,15,212,139
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Could not open data connection to port 54411: Connection refused
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

But i can connect and list its directory successfully in linux terminal.The problem is only in filezilla.(Failed to retrieve directory listing)

Comment: I don't see that your question involves ssh at all. FTP runs into firewall issues all the time because it was published while the US was still flying men into space to walk on the moon. It uses a series of ports, and can be interrupted by a remote firewall (which can be mitigated by passive mode) or your local firewall limiting your outbound access. Usually "No route to host" implies that your own network is the problem. Either way this is a network/firewall issue, not a protocol issue.

Comment: [This page](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) does a good job of describing FTP active and passive data transfers, and the issues they encounter.